# open url with parameters in default browser

Tags: go, browser

If we try to open a given URL from Go, it is quite easy as shown in the code below (for mac):

```
exec.Command("open", "https://google.com").Run()
```

But how do we do the same if the URL has parameters?

For example, if we try to open a facebook login URL: "https://www.facebook.com/v11.0/dialog/oauth?client_id=123456&redirect_uri=https://example/com", the command fails with exit status 1.

This is true even when we include backslashes for the special characters ?, & and =. The URL changes to `https://www.facebook.com/v11.0/dialog/oauth\?client_id\=123456\&redirect_uri\=https://example/com`.

The above URL opens in default browser if we use

`open https://www.facebook.com/v11.0/dialog/oauth\?client_id\=123456\&redirect_uri\=https://example/com`

command in terminal. But it fails when doing so from Go!

Is there a way to do the same from Go?

And yes, it can be done using `exec.Command("open", "-a", "safari", url)`. But this would not open the default browser, which is where the user is most likely signed in.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I launch a process that is not a file in Go (e.g. open a web page)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10377243/how-can-i-launch-a-process-that-is-not-a-file-in-go-e-g-open-a-web-page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually works without the backslash. Turns out the backslash is needed in terminal, because the terminal internally escapes the backslash before sending the string to the browser. But in case of go, it just sends the original string to the browser.

In Go use:

```
exec.Command("open", "https://www.facebook.com/v11.0/dialog/oauth?client_id=123456&redirect_uri=https://example/com")
```

From the terminal command line:

```
open https://www.facebook.com/v11.0/dialog/oauth\?client_id\=123456\&redirect_uri\=https://example/com
```

Answer (score 0):

Try appending backslash(\)

```
exec.Command("open", "https://www.facebook.com/v11.0/dialog/oauth\\?client_id/\\=123456/\\&redirect_uri/\\=https://example/com").Run()
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried this. It doesn't work either.

Comment: Could it be an issue in mac? because I tried it in ubuntu (with xdg-open) and it works fine.