# How To Convert Nextjs Typescript Golang Postgresql Web App Into Desktop App

Tags: postgresql, go, next.js, web-applications, desktop-application

I have created a website application using nextjs typescript for the frontend and golang echo for the backend with a postgresql database. How do I create the desktop version (.exe)? Is there a way that I can do to create a desktop version of my website application? especially for Windows installers, so users can install them on their respective desktops and don't need to be connected to the internet.

Comment: Your could use [`os/exec`](https://pkg.go.dev/os/exec#Cmd.Start) to [start a browser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10380889/11810946) (with your Go app serving everything locally); alternatively you could use something like [wails](https://github.com/wailsapp/wails). Note that this assumes that everything (e.g. postgres) will run on the users PC.

Comment: can you tell me the complete tutorial of wails? because the official website is not complete

Comment: Sorry - requests for tutorials are [off topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).